# Delete rows from Excel using OpenXML

Tags: excel, openxml

I need to delete certain rows from an excel file. The excel file is a template and may have extra rows, which have to be deleted for the final output. However deletion of the cells corrupts the file. The code is as simple as follows

```
Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

foreach (var row in sheetData.Elements<Row>().
Where(r => r.RowIndex.Value >= rowIndex && r.RowIndex.Value < rowIndex +  count).ToList())
{
  row.Remove();
}
```

Alternatively, I tried setting the existing cells to blank values.

```
Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
foreach (var row in sheetData.Elements<Row>().
Where(r => r.RowIndex.Value >= rowIndex && r.RowIndex.Value < rowIndex + count).ToList())
{
  IEnumerable<Cell> cells = row.Elements<Cell>().ToList();
  if (cells != null)
  {
    foreach (Cell cell in cells)
    {
      if (cell.CellValue != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.CellValue.Text))
      {
        cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
        cell.CellValue = new CellValue("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My file always gets corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the final streams to save the worksheet/workbooks, had a mismatch in the sizes.